# JavaScript object related question that what will be the output of below code?

Tags: javascript, object

```js
var x = 3;
var one = {
  x:2,
  two: {
    x:1,
    three:function(){
        return this.x;
      
    }
  }
}

var go = one.two.three;

 console.log(one.two.three() + "" + go());
```

Anyone can explain to me why output coming 13 why not 1-undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting. I think it has something to do with scopes.

```js
console.log(one.two.three() + "" + go());
//equals console.log(1 + "" + 3);
```

will output `13` (String) because:

- `one.two.three()` returns `1`
- `go()` returns `3`
- those numbers are concatenated into String with `""` (empty string) in between (instead of `-` as you may have asked)

---

**Why `go()` returns `3`**

```js
var x = 3;

// var go = one.two.three;
// equals 
var go = function() {
  return this.x
}
```

The declaration `var go = one.two.three;` assigns `one.two`'s `three` method as a function into the variable `go` in the global scope. The same scope with `go`, `one`, and `x` (with the value `3`), that was declared before declaring `one` and `go` (`var x= 3;`).

Based on your whole codes, `this.x`'s `this` is in the global scope. and `this.x` is `3`. So running `go()` returns `3`.

`one.two.three` is a global function
→ notice there's no `()`, so assigning a function to global scope's variable `go` will make the function's scope global.
→ `go` function is run under global's scope

---

**Why `one.two.three()` returns `1`**

Well, `one.two.three` is a method inside the object `two`, which is inside the object `one`. While the definition looks the same,

```js
function() {
  return this.x;
}
```

when you run `three` method of `two` object, `return this.x`'s `this` refers to the method's parent object (which is `two`, `three`'s parent object is `two`).
So,
`this.x` refers to
`two.x` which is `1`.

Hence, in this case `return this.x;` outputs `1`.

`one.two.three()` is `1`
→ notice the `()` which means `run the function`
→ `three` method is run under `two`'s scope

---

**Addition**

This will output `1-undefined` because:

- `y` is not defined in the global/`one`/`go` scope
- I use `-` as a delimiter in `console.log`

```js
var one = {
  y:2,
  two: {
    y: 1,
    three:function(){
        return this.y;
      
    }
  }
}

var go = one.two.three;

console.log(one.two.three() + "-" + go());
```

Answer (score 4):

`this` keyword has a different binding that can change during runtime, depending on how the function was invoked.

When a function is on an object, and is accessed through that object, it's `this` context will be that object (unless explicitly bound otherwise, but I'll add notes on that later). This means `this.x` is referencing the same variable as `one.two.x`

When you reference that same function into a global variable, the `this` context becomes the global space (e.g. the `window` object on browsers, or `globalThis` in NodeJS). When this happens, `this.x` is now referencing global variable `x`.

There are other situations where `this` context rules are different, such as function closures or class functions.

Functions also have `.bind` method that returns a new function with an explicitly bound `this` variable.

e.g:

```js
var x = 3;
var one = {
  x:2,
  two: {
    x:1,
    three:function(){
        return this.x;
      
    }
  }
}

one.two.three = one.two.three.bind(one);

var go = one.two.three;

console.log(one.two.three() + "" + go()); // prints 22
```

There are also arrow functions, which implicitly have the `this` context bound to it's lexical scope... e.g:

```js
var x = 3;
var one = {
  x:2,
  two: {
    x:1,
    three: () => {
        return this.x;

    }
  }
}


var go = one.two.three;

console.log(one.two.three() + "" + go()); // prints 33
```

This above example prints 33, because the lexical scope is the global scope, thus `this.x` is referencing global variable `x`.

Hope this answers your question without creating more questions.

Further Reading:

- [this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Bind method new for me but thanks for give example :)
Thanks for the simple explanation :)

Answer (score -1):

To assign an object method to a variable, it needs to be bandaged using the bind() function, and if the global variable window is passed to the context, the answer will be 13

```
*var go = one.two.three.bind(window);*
```

if the object is one the answer will be 12

```
*var go = one.two.three.bind(one);*
```

if the object is two the answer will be 11

```
*var go = one.two.three.bind(two);*
```